# What is the purpose of QException?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtconcurrent, qexception

In Qt 5.0 - Qt Introduced the `QException` class.

What is benifit of inheriting from this class? What if we throw a class that does not inherit from the QException class?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qexception.html) (emphasis mine): `The QException class provides a base class` **`for exceptions that can [be] transferred across threads`**.

Comment: @Laszlo I am not satisfied that much... though i have voted your comment as useful..

Comment: Why are you not explaining what is missing rather than obsoleting the thread?

Answer (score 14):

In short, you can find the answers by reading the relatively short [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qexception.html).

---

> Q: What is benefit of inheriting from this class?

This is the corresponding part of the documentation:

> The QException class provides a base class for exceptions that can transferred across threads.

In addition to that, it integrates pretty well with the `QtConcurrent` feature set, including `QFuture`.

---

> Q: What if we throw a class that does not inherit from the QException class?

This is the corresponding part of the documentation:

> If you throw an exception that is not a subclass of QException, the Qt functions will throw a QUnhandledException in the receiver thread.

Comment: I have already had gone through this documentation part... but Some things are still unclear..

Comment: @DesigningLives: I have no idea what is unclear, especially without questions.

Comment: I have already had gone through this documentation part... but Some things are still unclear.. as 
- What if Qt functions will throw a QUnhandledException in the receiver thread ??

- Is this class is Useful to only when threading i.e. `QtConcurrent`  or `QFuture` will come in picture..??

- I can Make own Class and throw that, in General case will it make difference ?

Comment: @DesigningLives: Hmm, based on your questions, the basics are not in place. Please start the reading in here: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtconcurrent-index.html